# Two submit button - default submit not working because of other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I have two submit buttons in a php file take_test:-

```
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: index.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
} 

// Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

// We can display the user's username to them by reading it from the session array.  Remember that because 
// a username is user submitted content we must use htmlentities on it before displaying it to the user. 
?> 


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-AU">

 <head>
 <title>OSTA - Take Test</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"     src="editarea/edit_area/edit_area_full.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
 <h1> OSTA - Take Test</h1>
</div><!-- end header -->

<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li>Hello <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF- 8'); ?></li>
<li><a href="s_assignments.php">Assignments</a></li>
<li><a href="s_edit_account.php">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="s_logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end nav -->

<div class="content">   
<?php   
echo "<form id='code' action='take_test.php' method='post'>";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


if(isset($_POST['next']))
{

$aa = $_POST['source'];
//foreach($aa as $k) :
$query = "INSERT INTO student_test(status,user_name,aaid,qqid,answer,submit_time)
VALUES('1','{$_SESSION['user'] ['username']}','{$_POST['edit']}','{$_POST['qid']}','{$aa}',NOW())";
$rest5=mysqli_query($con,$query);
//endforeach;

//}

//if (!$rest)
//{
//  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
//}
$qry="SELECT qid FROM questions where aid={$_POST['edit']}
ORDER BY qid DESC
LIMIT 1";
$restfinal=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$rowfinal = mysqli_fetch_array($restfinal);
$qidfinal = $rowfinal['qid'];
if ($qidfinal==$_POST['qid'])
{   
echo "Test Submitted Successfully.";
sleep( 3 );
header("Location: s_assignments.php");
echo "Test Submitted Successfully.";
}
}


if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    $id2 = $_POST['edit'];


    if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {
    $a=$_POST['a'];
    if(!isset($a)){
        $a=0;
    }}


    if(!isset($a)){
        $a=0;
    }
//$res=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from assignments where a_id='$id'");
$res1 = mysqli_query($con,"Select n_question from assignments where a_id='$id2'");  
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1);
$n_q = $row1['n_question'];
$res8=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from questions where aid='$id2' LIMIT 1 OFFSET  $a");

}

echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>";
echo "<tr>

<th>Question</th>
</tr>";

while($rowt = mysqli_fetch_array($res8))
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $rowt['question'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type ='hidden' id='qid' name ='qid'    value=".$rowt['qid']."></td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type ='hidden' id='aid' name ='edit' value=".$rowt['aid']."></td>";         
    //echo "<td>"."<input type ='hidden' id='id' name ='id' value=".$id.">    </td>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"."<hr>"."<td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<td>"."<label for='lang'>Select Language:</label>
    <select name='lang' id='lang'>
    <option value='7'>Ada (gnat-4.3.2)</option>
    <option value='13'>Assembler (nasm-2.07)</option>
    <option value='45'>Assembler (gcc-4.3.4)</option>
    <option value='104'>AWK (gawk) (gawk-3.1.6)</option>
    <option value='105'>AWK (mawk) (mawk-1.3.3)</option>
    <option value='28'>Bash (bash 4.0.35)</option>
    <option value='110'>bc (bc-1.06.95)</option>
    <option value='12'>Brainf**k (bff-1.0.3.1)</option>
    <option value='11'>C (gcc-4.3.4)</option>
    <option value='27'>C# (mono-2.8)</option>
    <option value='1' selected='selected'>C++ (gcc-4.3.4)</option>
    <option value='44'>C++0x (gcc-4.5.1)</option>
    <option value='34'>C99 strict (gcc-4.3.4)</option>
    <option value='14'>CLIPS (clips 6.24)</option>
    <option value='111'>Clojure (clojure 1.1.0)</option>
    <option value='118'>COBOL (open-cobol-1.0)</option>
    <option value='106'>COBOL 85 (tinycobol-0.65.9)</option>
    <option value='32'>Common Lisp (clisp) (clisp 2.47)</option>
    <option value='102'>D (dmd) (dmd-2.042)</option>
    <option value='36'>Erlang (erl-5.7.3)</option>
    <option value='124'>F# (fsharp-2.0.0)</option>
    <option value='123'>Factor (factor-0.93)</option>
    <option value='125'>Falcon (falcon-0.9.6.6)</option>
    <option value='107'>Forth (gforth-0.7.0)</option>
    <option value='5'>Fortran (gfortran-4.3.4)</option>
    <option value='114'>Go (gc-2010-07-14)</option>
    <option value='121'>Groovy (groovy-1.7)</option>
    <option value='21'>Haskell (ghc-6.8.2)</option>
    <option value='16'>Icon (iconc 9.4.3)</option>
    <option value='9'>Intercal (c-intercal 28.0-r1)</option>
    <option value='10'>Java (sun-jdk-1.6.0.17)</option>
    <option value='35'>JavaScript (rhino) (rhino-1.6.5)</option>
    <option value='112'>JavaScript (spidermonkey) (spidermonkey-1.7)</option>
    <option value='26'>Lua (luac 5.1.4)</option>
    <option value='30'>Nemerle (ncc 0.9.3)</option>
    <option value='25'>Nice (nicec 0.9.6)</option>
    <option value='122'>Nimrod (nimrod-0.8.8)</option>
    <option value='43'>Objective-C (gcc-4.5.1)</option>
    <option value='8'>Ocaml (ocamlopt 3.10.2)</option>
    <option value='119'>Oz (mozart-1.4.0)</option>
    <option value='22'>Pascal (fpc) (fpc 2.2.0)</option>
    <option value='2'>Pascal (gpc) (gpc 20070904)</option>
    <option value='3'>Perl (perl 5.12.1)</option>
    <option value='54'>Perl 6 (rakudo-2010.08)</option>
    <option value='29'>PHP (php 5.2.11)</option>
    <option value='19'>Pike (pike 7.6.86)</option>
    <option value='108'>Prolog (gnu) (gprolog-1.3.1)</option>
    <option value='15'>Prolog (swi) (swipl 5.6.64)</option>
    <option value='4'>Python (python 2.6.4)</option>
    <option value='116'>Python 3 (python-3.1.2)</option>
    <option value='117'>R (R-2.11.1)</option>
    <option value='17'>Ruby (ruby-1.9.2)</option>
    <option value='39'>Scala (scala-2.8.0.final)</option>
    <option value='33'>Scheme (guile) (guile 1.8.5)</option>
    <option value='23'>Smalltalk (gst 3.1)</option>
    <option value='40'>SQL (sqlite3-3.7.3)</option>
    <option value='38'>Tcl (tclsh 8.5.7)</option>
    <option value='62'>Text (text 6.10)</option>
    <option value='115'>Unlambda (unlambda-2.0.0)</option>
    <option value='101'>Visual Basic .NET (mono-2.4.2.3)</option>
    <option value='6'>Whitespace (wspace 0.3)</option>
    </select>". "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>"."<label for='source'>Source Code:</label>"."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>"."<textarea cols='80' rows='12' name='source' id ='source'>    </textarea>"."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "<tr>";//echo "<br />";
echo "<td>"."<label for='input'>Input: <span class='description'>(Data that will be   given to the program on the stdin.)</span></label>";
//echo "<br />";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"."<textarea cols='40' rows='3' name='input' id='input'></textarea>". "  </td>";
echo "</tr>";
$a=$a+1;
echo "<input type='hidden' value='$a' name='a'>";
   //   echo "<td>"."<a href='take_test.php'> "
   //echo "<td>"."<input type ='submit' name ='compile' value='Compile Code'>"."</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<input type='submit' name='compile' id='compile' value='Compile   Code'>"."</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<input type ='submit' name ='next' value='Next Question'>"."</td>";
  echo "</table>"; 

  echo"</form>";

  ?>
  <div id="response">
        <div class="meta"></div>
        <div class="output"></div>
</div>
</div><!-- end content -->

<div class="footer">
<p>designed by  |  &copy;  </p>
</div><!-- end footer -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
editAreaLoader.init({
id : "source"       // textarea id
,syntax: "css"          // syntax to be uses for highgliting
,start_highlight: true      // to display with highlight mode on start-up
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="../jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

One submit name=next i am detecting through 
    if(isset($_POST['next']))
and the other through 
    
    Here is the code for script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//$('input[name=compile]').on('click',function(){
//  $(this).closest("#code")[0].submit();})
//$('#compile').on('click', function() {
    $('#code').submit( function(){

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var source = $('textarea#source').val();

    if( source == '' ) {
        alert( 'No source code provided');
        return false;
    }

    $(this).append('<div class="loading">Processing...</div>');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data + '&process=1',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            $('.loading').remove();
            $('.cmpinfo').remove();
            $('#response').show();
            //alert(response);
            console.log(response.raw);
            if( response.status == 'success' ) {
                $('.meta').text( response.meta );
                $('.output').html('<strong>Output</strong>: <br><br><pre>' + response.output + '</pre>');

                if( response.cmpinfo ) {
                    $('.cmpinfo').remove();
                    $('.meta').after('<div class="cmpinfo"></div>');
                    $('.cmpinfo').html('<strong>Compiler Info: </strong> <br><br>' + response.cmpinfo );
                }

            } else {
                //$('.output').html('<pre>' + response + '</pre>');
                alert( response.output );
            }
            //alert( response.msg );
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is whenever I click on either compile button or next button it considers compile button only. If i remove script file the next button runs perfectly.
Please give any suggestion.
I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: This is a bit... long. Could you shorten your code to a minimal example that's enough to replicate your issue?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the Compile button? Does the Next button work fine in that case?

Comment: you are using $('#code') but i didn't found any tag with id="code". and if(isset($_POST['next'])) only check that the variable is set or not.

Comment: 1.)There are no errors Mr. putvande                              2.)Sorry Mr. Ben for the mess but I thought it would be appropriate to provide the whole thing.                                      3.)exactly Mr.Harry the whole thing depends on script.js file ,if thats commented out, only then the next button works. Not if the compile button is commented.                                             4.)the #code is the id of the form in take_test.php file. And I am using if(isset($_POST['next'])) to check when next button is hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$('#code').submit` function in the JS file seems to be the problem. Since both buttons in your PHP are submit buttons, clicking on either of those two buttons will trigger the form submit action and it in-turn is triggering the AJAX request for process.php.

If the script file is commented out, then the default action page mentioned in your form tag is called and that is the reason why your next button works when the script is commented out.

You should add a control within the JS file to check which of those submit buttons was actually clicked by the user and then do the appropriate action. The below is a very basic sample for your reference:

**HTML**

```
<form id="code" action="aa.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="compile" value="compile"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="next" value="next"/>
</form>
```

**JS (to be executed on DOM ready)**

```
var buttonpressed;
$('.button').click(function() {
    buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name');
}); //This will set the name of the button that was clicked to the buttonpressed variable whenever a button is clicked

$('#code').submit(function() {
//The below lines check for the button's name upon form submit and then process accordingly
    if(buttonpressed=="next") alert("Add code to next");
    else alert("Add code to compile");
    buttonpressed='';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sir, this is the exact problem which you mentioned above. I tried the above code. Now, only compile button is working and that too because of if(isset($_POST['next'])) and if I remove this, my logic of moving to next question will be gone. Is there any alternative for compile button.

Comment: @master Can you please edit the question and post your modified code in it? I would like to see if there are any issues with your modified code.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var buttonpressed;
 $('.button').click(function() {
     buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name');
 }); //This will set the name of the button that was clicked to the buttonpressed variable whenever a button is clicked

 $('#code').submit(function() {
 //The below lines check for the button's name upon form submit and then process accordingly
     if(buttonpressed=="next") alert("Add code to next");
     else alert("Add code to compile");
     buttonpressed='';
     return false;
 });//check submit button ends
)};// jquery ends

Comment: @master this is the same as what I gave you. you have to do the following: (1) modify the compile and next button code to be inline with what I provided above. (2) replace the alerts (like `alert("Add code to next");`) with the actions that are required on the corresponding button press. For example, all contents of the JS file starting from the `var data` line to the line before the `return false;` should go into the else part of the above loop.

Comment: I did that only but i can't put that here because stackoverflow word limit. Anyway it should atleast give an alert when either of the button is clicked. But is not giving the alert in either of the case.

Comment: @master Did you also add the `class=button` part to your submit buttons? Refer to this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/hHpNc/) for a working version of the sample I gave you. Also, if possible share some link for your code if it cannot be posted here. It is difficult to debug without seeing the current version.

Comment: Yes I did class=button. Please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hHpNc/2/). But the problem is I can't move the content of next button, its all php code.

Comment: @master Refer this [version](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/hHpNc/). This would make an AJAX call if the button name is compile. Else it would use the default form submit action (which is to redirect to my personal PHP page. Change that to take_test.php).

Comment: Awesome it worked. Thankyou very very much @Harry. I appreciate the effort. Just one more question, is this compatible with older browsers especially IE.

Comment: @master The code that we used was mostly jquery items, so it should work in any browser that jquery supports. Refer [here](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) for jquery browser support.

Comment: @master Please create another question with your current code. Reason I say this is not because I don't want to help you but because the others might give you a better solution too.